# Update to XML attribues list from datagrid

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Morning:

Using the below method `GetProductsPriceList()` i read attributes of the selective nodes from the XML file and load it to the datagrid.

I edit the values of Visible & Price columns and save back to the XML File.

```
private ObservableCollection<Products> GetProductsPriceList()
{
    productpricelist = new ObservableCollection<Products>();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"C:\xmltest\26112023.txt");
    foreach (XmlElement pn in doc.SelectNodes("/Data/Products/*"))
    {
        var productlist = new Products
        {
            Mainproduct = pn.LocalName.ToString(),
            Name = pn.GetAttribute("Name"),
            Price = pn.SelectSingleNode(".//ProductPrice/@Price")?.Value,
            Visible = pn.SelectSingleNode(".//ProductVisibility/@Visible")?.Value,
            NameIcon = pn.GetAttribute("DefaultIconName")
        };
        productpricelist.Add(productlist);
    }

    return productpricelist;
}
```

My issue here, when i try to save to the xml file with  datagrid view contents of `Price & Visible attributes` only one value is applied to all the attributes of `Price & Visible` .

**Expected result:** Each Price & Visible vlaues from datagrid should be applied to each product of the  `Price & Visible attributes`.

During debug i can see the `pp.Visible` & `pp.Price` has the right contents i.e. the values entered in the datagrid.

I dont know what is wrong with my approcah with Foreach loop? How can i fix this? thanks

`Price` is an `attribute` of `ProductPrice` and
`Visible` is an `attribute` of `ProductVisibility` under `Visibilities`

```
private void Execute(object parm) //method to save back to the xml file price & visible attributes for each products 
{

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(@"C:\xmltest\26112023.txt");
    foreach (Products pp in productpricelist)
    {
        foreach (XmlElement pn in doc.SelectNodes("/Data/Products/*"))
    {

        
            foreach (XmlNode visibility in pn.SelectNodes("Visibilities"))
            {
                foreach (XmlNode productVisibilty in visibility.SelectNodes("ProductVisibility"))
                {
                    productVisibilty.Attributes["Visible"].InnerText = pp.Visible;

                    foreach (XmlNode price in productVisibilty.SelectNodes("Prices"))
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode productPrice in price.SelectNodes("ProductPrice"))
                        {
                            productPrice.Attributes["Price"].InnerText = pp.Price;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            }
doc.Save(@"C:\xmltest\26112023_.txt");
}
```

Sample XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <ShippingMethodsReferences />
  <Products>
    <ProductApple ID="77f9df03-7525-44d7-b08d-dcf106b44969" Sys_Type="Library.Domain.Products.ProductApple" Sys_ImportStrategy="UpdateOnly" DefaultIconName="Xerox_10x8x2_R_Sticker.png" Profile="Fruits" DefaultOutputProfileTypeFullName="Output" Name="(10x8)x2 H Rectangular">
      <ShippingMethodPrices ImportStrategy="Replace" />
      <Visibilities ImportStrategy="Replace">
        <ProductVisibility ID="adfa5eca-3f58-4107-8738-5b9b1c0b666f" Sys_GlobalUniqueId="adfa5eca-3f58-4107-8738-5b9b1c0b666f" Sys_ReplicationId="ee46c28d-7b82-447d-a3a9-a67e0e4bbd5b" Sys_Type="ProductVisi" Activated="True" OverrideServerProductPrices="False" PhotoSource="EndUserPhotos" BackgroundColor="Default" Icon="" Image="" IsUnusableByLicense="False" MaxDate="2999-12-31" MinDate="1900-01-01" Name="" OrderableObjectVisibility="Visible" Visible="True" ReplicationId="ee46c28d-7b82-447d-a3a9-a67e0e4bbd5b">
          <Prices ImportStrategy="Replace">
            <ProductPrice ID="e558ceed-1e64-4540-8958-0203fea2b53b" Sys_GlobalUniqueId="e558ceed-1e64-4540-8958-0203fea2b53b" Sys_ReplicationId="2810c015-da9b-4aa9-ad43-ac7c02341b79" Sys_Type="Library.Domain.ProductPrice" FixFee="0" ServiceFee="0" Mode="Replace" FromQuantity="1" Price="0" ProductPriceType="PerPageQuantity" ReplicationId="2810c015-da9b-4aa9-ad43-ac7c02341b79" />
          </Prices>
        </ProductVisibility>
      </Visibilities>
    </ProductApple>
    <ProductSolo ID="7c1302d8-8832-451b-be64-c5d048d0332f" Sys_Type="Library.Domain.Products.ProductApple" Sys_ImportStrategy="UpdateOnly" DefaultIconName="Xerox_10x8x2_R_Metallic.png" Profile="Fruits" DefaultOutputProfileTypeFullName="Output" Name="(10x8)x2 H Rectangular">
      <ShippingMethodPrices ImportStrategy="Replace" />
      <Visibilities ImportStrategy="Replace">
        <ProductVisibility ID="078f6e6a-895c-4957-b808-2b38589ba4cd" Sys_GlobalUniqueId="078f6e6a-895c-4957-b808-2b38589ba4cd" Sys_ReplicationId="e0ca0706-0113-4479-ab47-59d2b14bf837" Sys_Type="ProductVisi" Activated="True" OverrideServerProductPrices="False" PhotoSource="EndUserPhotos" BackgroundColor="Default" Icon="" Image="" IsUnusableByLicense="False" MaxDate="2999-12-31" MinDate="1900-01-01" Name="" OrderableObjectVisibility="Visible" Visible="True" ReplicationId="e0ca0706-0113-4479-ab47-59d2b14bf837">
          <Prices ImportStrategy="Replace">
            <ProductPrice ID="0c14f953-9f75-4e24-9c38-245027107167" Sys_GlobalUniqueId="0c14f953-9f75-4e24-9c38-245027107167" Sys_ReplicationId="2d243d53-cd0c-4a92-adea-919a9bcb427d" Sys_Type="Library.Domain.ProductPrice" FixFee="0" ServiceFee="0" Mode="Replace" FromQuantity="1" Price="0" ProductPriceType="PerPageQuantity" ReplicationId="2d243d53-cd0c-4a92-adea-919a9bcb427d" />
          </Prices>
        </ProductVisibility>
      </Visibilities>
    </ProductSolo>
    </Data>
</Products>
```

Comment: When you save, you over write the entire file. So I would translate the whole file into a collection of products. Even if you edit some sub selection of them.  Then translate the whole list of products back to xml and save the file.  But I would prefer to just serialise a class to disk and deserialise the lot back if I could control what the xml file looks like.

Comment: @Andy actually i tried to serialize / deserialize but its not working becasue its a complicated file.  `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Products>));
 using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(FilePath, Encoding.UTF8))
 serializer.Serialize(writer, ProductPriceList);`
 `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<Products>));
 using (Stream str = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open))
 return (ObservableCollection<Products>)serializer.Deserialize(str);`

Comment: I usually translate from viewmodels to dto models using automapper and then would serialise the dto.  And of course back again.  Does your file have to look like that with attributes?

Comment: @Andy: i'm also using viewmodel but not dto models(never used). Yes this xml file is already set in this way i cant change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before

```
            foreach (XmlNode visibility in pn.SelectNodes("Visibilities"))
            {
                foreach (XmlNode productVisibilty in visibility.SelectNodes("ProductVisibility"))
                {
                    productVisibilty.Attributes["Visible"].InnerText = pp.Visible;

                    foreach (XmlNode price in productVisibilty.SelectNodes("Prices"))
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode productPrice in price.SelectNodes("ProductPrice"))
                        {
                            productPrice.Attributes["Price"].InnerText = pp.Price;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

you have to check, if the product in pp equals the product in pn. If not you set Visible and Price Attribute of all Products selected with `doc.SelectNodes("/Data/Products/*")` instead of only the product in pp.

Without knowing the business model exactly, it's not possible for me to say exactly how to check if the product in pp is equal to the product in pn. It could maybe go like this, if Mainprduct is the primary key of the products:

```
    if( pp.Mainproduct == pn.LocalName.ToString())
    {
        // TODO: Insert here the code from above
    }
```

Comment: Hello Ruedi, thanks so much for your help. How can i check `product in pp equals the product in pn`? I'm not sure how to compare it with my limited knowledge. thanks

Comment: Ho Ruedi: My apoligize just updated the questions with ViewModel. I didnt quite understand to compare the `Products MainProduct with PP.LocalName`, I just tried it worked for certain nodes but not for all the nodes. What do you think? May be you could tell me further from the viewmodel. thanks

Comment: @user838691: 
a) With which columns resp. values ​​can you uniquely identify a product in the table? Apparently the MainProduct column is not sufficient for this. b) Are there also empty cells in the table?

Comment: @user838691: Another thing is. Business Model is not the same as the View Model. The Business Mode defines among other things, how a product can uniquely identified in the xml. Or say it in other words: How does you know exactly which product in the table is wich product resp. node in the xml file? 
Which fields resp. values ​​have to match?

Comment: you're correct, finally i found a solution by using an identifier for each node `if (pp.SysId == pn.GetAttribute("Sys_Oid").ToString())`. Thanks again.